# Поиск подпоследовательности в битовой строке

Tags: c++, алгоритм, битовые-операции

Задача: Дана строка состоящая из нулей и единиц, и целое число `k`. Нужно проверить что каждое двоичное число длинной `k` является подпоследовательностью строки.

Пример 1:
Input: s = "00110110", k = 2
Output: true

Пример 2:
Input: s = "0110", k = 1
Output: true

Огриничения:

```
1 <= s.length <= 5 * 10^5
1 <= k <= 20
```

Решение:

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool hasAllCodes(string s, int k) {
        const int count = 2 << (k - 1);
        int m = 0;

        if (count >= s.size())
            return false;
    
        for (unsigned int value = 0; value <= count; ++value)
        {
            bool flag = false;
            for (size_t i = 0; i <= s.size() - k; ++i)
            {
                unsigned int current = toValue(s, i, k);
                if (value == current)
                {
                    ++m;
                    if (m == count)
                        return true;
                    flag = true;
                    break;
                }
           }
           if (!flag)
              return false;
         }

        if (m == count)
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    unsigned int toValue(const string& s, size_t i, size_t k)
    {
        unsigned int value = 0;
        for (int j = i; j < i + k; j++)
        {
            if (s[j] == '1')
            value++;
        
            value = value << 1;
        }
        value = value >> 1;
        return value;
    }
};
```

Как реализовать эффективнее?

Comment: Заведите сопоставление k -> bool и отмечайте там попадания соответствующего k за один проход.

Answer (score 1):

Эффективнее идти по строке, на каждом шаге удаляя старший бит из текущего числа, сдвигая его влево, добавляя младший бит из следующей цифры.

Получив очередное число, выставляем соответствующий бит в bitset или в массиве байтов или bool длиной 2^k. При этом можно сразу подсчитывать установленные значения или в конце посчитать, что их 2^k